# What's this `slot-missing: Invalid slot name: "#<transient-prefix transient-prefix>", :incompatible`

Tags: magit

After updating to magit 20190517.1750 from ELPA, I've got this warning

`slot-missing: Invalid slot name: "#<transient-prefix transient-prefix>", :incompatible`

which breaks a lot of magit functionality.  Does somebody know a fix or a quick workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Update the `transient` package and restart Emacs.

---

1. The `incompatible` object slot was added fairly recently to the `transient-prefix` class. I do not use `package.el` myself, but believe that normally it updates all packages at once but also supports just updating one package. Maybe you did the latter.
2. Updating a package does not unload the previously loaded version and then load the new version. It is even possible to end up with half of the old version and half of the new version being loaded. E.g. if the library `foo-bar` is already loaded before you update the package `foo` and then you do something that causes library `foo-baz` to be loaded, then the `foo-bar` from the previous version is loaded alongside the `foo-baz` of the new version.

So maybe you actually did update `transient` at the same time at `magit`, but because `transient` was already loaded and (parts of) `magit` were not you ended up with incompatible versions installed.

You should **always** restart Emacs after updating packages. You can also forgo doing so (it often works or you won't notice the issues), but before you report an issue you **must** restart to test whether that "fixes" the issue.

---

If after doing all that you still get this error, then something™ is trying to use `transient` before that has been loaded. Explicitly `(require 'transient)` near the beginning of your init file might be good enough as a workaround. But of course it would be better to figure out the identity of something™.

Comment: Can you elaborate? If this is because the package needs to be recompiled, mention it. As is, your answer is lacking in content.

Comment: Well, I've tried to remove `magit` and `transient` from ELPA packages.  Restarted Emacs, reinstalled them, restarted Emacs.  I've got a different but related error now: `progn: Symbol’s function definition is void: transient-append-suffix` I'd rather stick to the ELPA distribution for now as I don't want to spend to much time on package management issues.

Comment: Sounds like something is trying to use `transient` before that has been loaded. Explicitly `(require 'transient)` near the beginning of your init file might be good enough as a workaround.

Comment: I've tried to require transient early and now I seem to be back to the magit problem: `error: magit-dispatch is not a transient command`.

Comment: @TheDude did you ever fix this? I'm getting slot errors from forge after a while away from emacs and a package update from straight.

Answer (score 2):

So the solutions seem to be as @tarsius suggested to `(require 'transient)` package early on in the init.el and to reinstall the `magit` package from ELPA.  Now everything seem to work again.

Comment: This worked for me as well.